# Can I set a id to the div from the fields_for?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I want to set an id to the div which from the fields_for, I write following code, but it does not work.

```html
<%= f.fields_for(:questions, @survey.questions.sort_by(&:sort), {:id => "myId"}) do |question_form| %>
```

When I check the source of the web page, I get:

```html
<div class="fields ui-sortable-handle"> 
...
<div>
```

I want to get result which is like:

```html
<div class="fields ui-sortable-handle" id="myId">       
...  
</div>
```

Comment: did you try `<%= f.fields_for(:questions, @survey.questions.sort_by(&:sort), input_html: {id: "myId"}) do |question_form| %>`

Comment: Yes, it also does not work

Comment: i  checked in docs but couldn't find anything helpful if you really want  to add that then you can do with js and jquery , `$('.ui-sortable-handle').attr('id', 'myId');`

Answer (score 1):

[fields_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)

```
   <%= f.fields_for :questions, @survey.questions.sort_by(&:sort), html: {id: "MyId", class: "MyClass"} do |question_form| %>
      <!-- question_form block -->
    <%end%>
```

Comment: Sorry to reply late, but your answer also does not work.